# Visualisation of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, visualization

I am very new to R. I would like to create a matrix(?)/visulisation from the example input:

```
         x
V1_V2   16
V1_V3   16
V1_V4   24
V2_V3   36
V2_V4    8
V3_V4    0
```

The output would look like this:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4
V1  0 16 16 24
V2 16 0  36  8
V3 16 36  0  0
V4 24  8  0  0
```

The output can be done in any form as long as it is represented like above.

The dput() is shown below.

```
c(V1_V2 = 16, V1_V3 = 16, V1_V4 = 24, V1_V4 = 36, V2_V3 = 36, 
V2_V4 = 0, V3_V4 = 0)
```

The formula that created the current input is the following:

```
result <- do.call(cbind, combn(names(df_trial), 2, function(x) {
  setNames(data.frame(as.integer(df_trial[[x[1]]] == df_trial[[x[2]]])), paste0(x, collapse = '_'))
}, simplify = FALSE))
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Please make your input example reproducible. You could use `dput()` and paste its output here.

Comment: @sindri_baldur I have updated the post with dput().

Comment: You'll have explain your formula/function for how the zeros are inserted.

Comment: Paste the output as raw text not as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that

1. your expected output is a symmetric matrix; and
2. your data looks like the one shown at the beginning of this post, not like that `dput` one, which has duplicated names.

Then you can try this function

```
matrix_display <- function(key, val) {
    key <- strsplit(key, "_")
    nms <- unique(unlist(key))
    n <- length(nms)
    mat <- matrix(0, n, n, dimnames = list(nms, nms))
    for (i in seq_along(val)) {
      mat[key[[i]][[1L]], key[[i]][[2L]]] <- val[[i]]
      mat[key[[i]][[2L]], key[[i]][[1L]]] <- val[[i]]
    }
    mat
  }
```

If your `input_data` is a dataframe, and `keys` are row names, then

```
matrix_display(row.names(input_data), input_data$x)
```

else if your `input_data` is a named vector, then

```
matrix_display(names(input_data), input_data)
```

Output should look like this

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4
V1  0 16 16 24
V2 16  0 36  8
V3 16 36  0  0
V4 24  8  0  0
```